# json_encode method in PHP

Tags: php, json

Hi I recently came across an example of json_encode function. Very confused about 1 part:

```
<?php 

$runners=array{

'fname'=>5
'you' => 6
};

echo json_encode (array("runners"=>$runners));

?>
```

Question is, why can't the code on the last row simply be:

```
echo json_encode ($runners);
```

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on how you want to represent it. Which data structure do you expecting exactly?

Comment: Problem is your array declaration is incorrect you are using { .. } instead of ( .. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your array is wrogly used. It will use small brackets `()` not curly `{}`. So your array will become :

```
$runners=array(
  'fname' => 5,
  'you'   => 6
);
```

Now when you do `json_encode()` as: `echo json_encode ($runners);` you will get the output:

```
{"fname":5,"you":6}
```

And if you do :  `echo json_encode (array("runners"=>$runners));` you will get output:

```
{"runners":{"fname":5,"you":6}}
```

Comment: This answer seems to address the *actual* question rather than being just a comment about the syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your [array declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is incorrect and you will get a syntax error if you run the code. You should use `array(...)` not `array{...}`. And the values need to be comma-separated. For example:

```
array(
    key  => value,
    key2 => value2,
    key3 => value3,
    ...
)
```

The following should work:

```
$runners = array(
    'fname' => 5,
    'you'   => 6
);

echo json_encode($runners);
```

Output:

```
{"fname":5,"you":6}
```

**How are these two different**

The end result is different for both cases. When you do `json_encode(array("runners"=>$runners));`, the array is multi-dimensional, and the JSON output will change, too:

```
{"runners":{"fname":5,"you":6}}
```

**Which one should you use**

Depends. In the first array, you are simply creating two keys named `fname` and `you`, and in the second, you also add another key, `runners`, thereby making the array multi-dimensional. If you want that information to be present in the resulting JSON string, you should use the second one. If not, use the first one.

Comment: True, but I don't think the question is about this syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

First you have use `{` in array it is not correct. and you have not have `,` between array elements.
you can use both. but you have to access 2 json by different ways. depending in your choice.

for first (it should be best choice)   `echo json_encode ($runners);` you have one dimensional array.

```
 $runners=array(

    'fname'=>5,
    'you' => 6
    );
    echo json_encode ($runners);
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"fname":5,"you":6}
```

In second you have 2d array.

```
     $runners=array(

    'fname'=>5,
    'you' => 6
    );


  echo json_encode (array("runners"=>$runners));
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"runners":{"fname":5,"you":6}}
```

Live Demo : https://eval.in/92104