# How to Generate JSON PHP?

Tags: php, json

I want to generate JSON from PHP.. I have an array of values.
I want This kind of format.

```
{
"data":[
{ 
 "fresher_id":"1370345",
 "applier_id":"1370345",   
 "applier_type":"a",
 "status":"13"
}, 
{
 "fresher_id":"1370345",
 "applier_id":"1370345",
 "applier_type":"a",
 "status":"13"
},
 {
 "fresher_id":"1370345",
 "applier_id":"1370345",
 "applier_type":"a",
 "status":"13"

   }
  ]
 }
```

Now iam generating this way, but it getting server exception 500
through POSTMAN  it is working.

```
$data=array();
$i=0;
foreach($userid as $key)
{
$data[$i]['fresher_id']="1634152";
$data[$i]['applier_id']="1634152";
$data[$i]['applier_type']="a";
$data[$i]['status']=$status;
$i++;
}
$data=json_encode($data);

$data='{"data":'.$data.'}';

$apiurl=Yii::$app->params['apiurl'];
$client = new Client();
$url=$apiurl.'/v1/jobs/'.$jobid.'/applications/';
$request = $client->patch($url, array(
'headers' => array('Content-type' => 'application/json'),
'json' => $data));
}
```

Comment: Do you really need us to tell you `json_encode()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [json\_encode method in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233568/json-encode-method-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode() function to create json

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```